# What is the "Synonymizer" badge?

Tags: support, badges

I just found this [new badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1224/synonymizer) on the Badges list. It has no description, and no one has one. What is it? How can you get it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get it the first time the tag synonym you proposed is approved.

Comment: So, does this only work on Meta, not on Stack Overflow itself?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann, It is a new badge just being rolled out.  Give it time to be awarded on the other sites.

Comment: @Rebecca, will it be retro-ed?

Comment: @Lance Yes, it will be. I got it for a tag synonym I proposed time ago.